# Disable all related constraints from a table with Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE disable_all_constraints
  (p_owner      IN VARCHAR2,
   p_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
CURSOR check_status IS
      (SELECT status
       FROM all_constraints
       WHERE owner = p_owner 
       AND   table_name = p_table_name );
v_status     VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  OPEN check_status;
  FETCH check_status
  INTO v_status;
  IF (check_status %NOTFOUND) 
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Constraints added to the table, give me another table to process!');
  ELSE
  FOR cur IN (SELECT owner, constraint_name , table_name 
              FROM   all_constraints
              WHERE  owner = p_owner
              AND    table_name = p_table_name) 
      LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||cur.owner||'.'||cur.table_name||' MODIFY CONSTRAINT '||cur.constraint_name||' DISABLE CASCADE ';
      END LOOP;
  END IF;
  CLOSE check_status;
  SELECT DISTINCT status
  INTO   v_status 
  FROM   all_constraints
  WHERE  owner = p_owner
  AND table_name = p_table_name;
  IF  v_status = 'DISABLED'      
  THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('All related constraints disable succesufully!');
  ELSE 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Something went wrong, but that is impossible!');
  END IF; 
END;
```

So i wrote the above piece. I tested it and it does the job pretty well i think. But my question is, how correct is it or how bad is it? Can it be done in a much easier and optimal way so to speak? Thanks.

Comment: It looks correct to me but why do you have `CASCADE` following `DISABLE`?

Comment: because i have some tables that have relations to the respective table so that is why i used it...it has told me from the error when running the procedure etc

Comment: therefore with cascade option in addition to disable works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with the way you're doing this but there are a number of potential issues and some unnecessary code.

- Your first cursor is unnecessary, you're going to loop through ALL_CONSTRAINTS anyway - if you don't enter the loop then the table has no constraints
- You may attempt to disable already disabled constraints - you only need to select those constraints that are currently enabled.
- Your final select to see whether there are any non-disabled constraints will *always* fail if there is more than one status as you'll get a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception (for returning more than one row). This means that your final ELSE statement will never be entered.
- It's *highly* unlikely that a constraint will not be disabled without an exception being raised. I wouldn't even bother with the final check.

More generally, there's rarely a point in outputting information to screen. It requires someone to read it. It's *normally* better if everything just works, or an exception is raised in the event of an error.

I would simplify this massively to something like the following, which simply loops through the non-disabled constraints and disables them.

```
create or replace procedure disable_all_constraints (
    p_owner in varchar2
  , p_table_name in varchar2
    ) is

begin

   for cur in ( select owner || '.' || table_name as object
                     , constraint_name
                  from all_constraints
                 where owner = p_owner
                   and table_name = p_table_name
                   and status <> 'DISABLED'
                       ) loop

      execute immediate 'alter table ' || cur.object || ' 
                           modify constraint ' || cur.constraint_name || '
                           disable cascade';

   end loop;

end;
```

If you feel like you have to have the extra checks and printing this can be done more cleanly:

```
create or replace procedure disable_all_constraints (
    p_owner in varchar2
  , p_table_name in varchar2
    )  is

   l_has_constraint boolean := False;
   l_ct number;

begin

   for cur in ( select owner || '.' || table_name as object
                     , constraint_name
                  from all_constraints
                 where owner = p_owner
                   and table_name = p_table_name
                   and status <> 'DISABLED'
                       ) loop

      l_has_constraint := True;
      execute immediate 'alter table ' || cur.object || ' 
                           modify constraint ' || cur.constraint_name || '
                           disable cascade';

   end loop;

   if not l_has_constraint then
       dbms_output.put_line('No Constraints added to the table.');
   else
       select count(*) into l_ct
         from all_constraints
        where owner = p_owner
          and table_name = p_table_name
          and status <> 'DISABLED'
              ;

       if l_ct = 0 then
          dbms_output.put_line('All related constraints disable successfully');
       else
          dbms_output.put_line('Something went wrong, but that is impossible');
       end if;
    end if;


end;
```